# Presto Multi table Join with Broadcast Join Distribution

Tags: join, query-optimization, presto

I have 3 tables:

```
A
 - id1
 - data
```

```
B 
 - id1
 - id2
 - data
```

```
C
 - id2
 - data
```

- Table A is very small, while table B and C are potentially huge.
- Table B has the joining keys for both tables A and C. So, has to be present in the first join.
- From what I understand about Joins in Presto, when cost based
  optmizations are not enabled, the order of Join executions is the
  order of declaration of the Joins.
- Also, we would obviously want to
  have the smaller table A in the first Join operation as that will
  reduce the data size.
- So, this means the the first Join will be between tables A and B
- But, if I want to perform a distributed Join,
  then the build side (right side) of the Join should be the smaller
  table.
- So, when I come to the second Join between the result of AxB and C, inevitably the right side of the join ends up being the larger table.

Very curious on how people generally handle such a scenario in Presto. If the build side for the distributed Join had been the left side, then it would have flown naturally that we always order the smaller tables to the left.

The ideas of performing Joins in the order they are defined and expecting the right side table to be smaller for Distributed Joins seem contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

Presto generally performs the join in the declared order (when cost-based optimizations are off), but it tries to [avoid cross joins](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/sql/planner/iterative/rule/EliminateCrossJoins.java) if possible. If you run [EXPLAIN](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html) on your query, you should be able to see the actual join order for your query.

For the example above, you could avoid the cross joins manually by forcing a right-associative join with parenthesis, similar to how arithmetic works (e.g., `a - (b - c)`):

```sql
WITH 
   a(x) AS (VALUES(1)), 
   b(x,y) AS (VALUES (1,'a')), 
   c(y) AS (VALUES 'a')
SELECT * 
FROM c JOIN (b JOIN a USING (x)) USING (y)
```